# MySql stored procedure in workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am using MySQL benchmark. I have to create a table and write a procedure to read 10 from textfilnd load them to the created table.

I used the query:

```
use test; 
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_table`() 
BEGIN 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "D:/tablevalue.txt" 
INTO TABLE new_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; 

END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

But error like load data is not allowed in stored procedure, and then I used the query.

```
use test; 
drop procedure if exists `proctable`; 
DELIMITER $$ 

create definer =`root`@`localhost` procedure `proctable`() 
begin 

do sys_exec(concat('perl LOAD_DATA_INFILE.pl test.new_table ', 'D:\tablevalue.txt')); 

end $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

But data is not uploading from the file to the table.

If is there any other option let me know

Comment: Once creating the stored proc. Did you call the proc?

Comment: yep. i call procedure( call proctable()) but it saying.           Error Code: 1305
FUNCTION test.sys_exec does not exist

Comment: sorry its not saying any error. running but no row selected is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some restrictions on stored procedures. For example - it is not possible to use LOAD DATA INFILE command. Try to do it without procedures, just call your LOAD DATA INFILE statement as alone command.

[Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Comment: ok ok. is there any other option to upload data into table from text file by using store procedure?

Comment: Have a look at UDF, you could call it from stored routine, but I'd suggest to use simple LOAD DATA INFILE - without procedure.

Comment: will u please post a sample user define function for retrieving a data from text file to table my task?

Comment: I do not have this example. You should write `LOAD..DATA`-like function using `c` or other program language, then compile code and create UDF that uses this function. Here it is a link on documentation - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html. You can find some examples in the internet. But, as I said - it is not good way.